# How to add comment to a particular model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created a polls app in which there are two classes in models.py called Question and Choice. Question means the question for a poll and Choice means choices for each question for users to choose from and vote.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Is Published')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default= 0)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="Question_Image2", blank=True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.choice_text

    def vote_range(self):
        return range(0, self.votes)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Question,Choice

admin.site.register(Question)
admin.site.register(Choice)
```

Now, I want to add class "comments" and register comments field for each question so that any user can enter comments through details.html and comments should be displayed in results.html

Comment: Do you mean comment the code or add a field called comment?

Comment: Hello Arpan! Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please be kind and add some more things that show what you have already tried. The way you ask us to do things for you will not help you learn new things.

Comment: I mean please give me code for adding comment class in a way that i could add comment field for every question in polls app where users can comment and see their comments displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asking a lot - this site is generally for answering questions about code, not writing code from scratch. It sounds like you need to create a new model for storing comments and a form for adding to this model.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/) is a link to the Django docs about forms.
[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/) is a link to the Django docs about models.

Have a go at writing a form and the new model yourself, and if you run into problems, ask for help on Stack Overflow.

Good Luck.